# Install precompiled GRUB 2 to raw image

Tags: x86, qemu, grub, grub2

I have an ext4 image file which wants to be used as a disk image for qemu. I want to install GRUB to it. After some research I found the following commands:

Create the image with a size of 5 GB:

```
qemu-img create hd.img 5G
```

Mount it as a loop device:

```
sudo mount -o loop hd.img /mnt
```

Install GRUB to it:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt --no-floppy --recheck /dev/loop0
```

The qemu system should be an x86 system. And that's the problem: I'm not on i386 and I don't have GRUB installed on my host system. So I'm searching for a precompiled version of GRUB 2 which I could just copy to the image's file system. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, if you are using (for example) Debian, then you already have per-architecture/platform packages for the target components of grub - in the x86 case:

- grub-efi-amd64
- grub-efi-ia32
- grub-pc

If building from source, just specify `--target=<TARGET>` on your configure line, where TARGET in your case would be `i386-pc`, `i386-efi` or `x86_64-efi`.

Install by passing `--target=<TARGET>` to `grub-install`.